# d3.js Hierarchy - Position Children in Columns instead of one big row

Tags: node.js, reactjs, d3.js

I'm using a wrapper of `d3-hierarchy` for a React project called [d3-flextree](https://github.com/Klortho/d3-flextree) and while it's working great, when our tree has nodes with many children, the children end up taking up lots of horizontal space since they are all on the same level and it makes the tree very hard to look at with more than about 50 nodes.

Ideally, I'm looking for a setting or way to manipulate `d3-hierarchy` directly (would like to keep using `d3-flextree` but not required) to allow me to set a "Max Columns" property for each parent node and if the parent has more than that many children, they children are stacked in columns to utilize more vertical space.

This:

```
         P
         |
---------------------
| | | | | | | | | | |
v v v v v v v v v v v
C C C C C C C C C C C
```

Would become this:

```
      P
      |
   C<--->C
      |
   C<--->C
      |
   C<--->C
      |
   C<--->C
      |
   C<--->C
      |
   C<--->C
     ...
```

I've looked at similar questions and solutions such as looping through each generated node again after the tree is generated and putting them into this layout directly, but this doesn't help condense the tree since the space between parent nodes because of the length of their children stays the same. So if a node had 100 children and caused it to space out its siblings, that space wouldn't condense after altering the layout. It also can cause some nodes to overlap if there's many children that expand downward since this doesn't check to see if any of them are intersecting with existing subtrees.